# How to split ArrayList by occurence of something?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections

I have the following ArrayList

```
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6));
```

then it will be

```
[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Now I want to split the list into a subl ist by next occurrence of 1
so that output will be

```
[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4,5,6]]
```

How can this be done ? List of List like

```
List<List<Integer>> ll = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

And my attempt is

```
ListIterator<Integer> li = steps.listIterator();
List<List<Integer>> fl = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();

while (li.hasNext()) {

    if (li.next() == 1) {
        l.add(li.next());
    }

    fl.add(l);
}
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes it can be done, you need to write some code that will do it.

Comment: `List<List<Integer>> fl = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
                List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                
                while (li.hasNext()) {

                    if (li.next() == 1) {
                        y++;
                    }
                    l.add(li.next());
                    fl.add(l);
                }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you invoke `iterator.next()`, cursor in iterator will be moved on next position. You can rewrite your algorithm without using of `iterator` just with `foreach` loop to avoid errors with cursor moving.

For example:

```
    List<Integer> originalList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6));
    List<List<Integer>> finalList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> currentList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Integer current : originalList) {
        if (current == 1) {
            if (!currentList.isEmpty()) {
                finalList.add(currentList);
            }
            currentList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        currentList.add(current);
    }
    if (!currentList.isEmpty()) {
         finalList.add(currentList);
    }
```

or, if you have java 8,  with [StreamEx Library](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) you can make it even easier:

```
   List<List<Integer>> streamExList = StreamEx.of(originalList)
            .groupRuns((first, second) -> second != 1)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using a **subList**  method of **ArrayList** to create a new **ArrayList**

The working code is as below:

```
  List<Integer> steps = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6));
            ListIterator<Integer> li = steps.listIterator();
            List<List<Integer>> fl = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
            List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();
            while (li.hasNext()) {
                  if (li.next() == 1) {
                        indexes.add(li.nextIndex() - 1);
                  }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < indexes.size(); i++) {
                  if (indexes.size() - 1 != i) {
                        fl.add(steps.subList(indexes.get(i), indexes.get(i + 1)));
                  } else {
                        fl.add(steps.subList(indexes.get(i), steps.size()));
                  }
            }
            System.out.println(fl);
```

Yes, here i am using a new list called **indexes**, it is useful to add indexes of find positions. Here , OfCourse the indexes i assigned in new list (indexes) are are need to **-1**, so i **edited**.

**Note:**

You were using below code in loop:

```
if (li.next() == 1) {
        l.add(li.next());
    }
```

This has two time **li.next()**, better to assign it to some variable. it does mean if your using more than one time **li.next()** in your loop , the pointer will move to next position and you wont get the result you wan t and a runtime exception you may face is **NoSuchElementException**.